# Python in VSCode: What is the easiest way to switch to the correct environment?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I am trying to use Python3 in VS code and for some reason, the VS terminal only will read my macOS system installed version of Python 2.7. I have several other interpreters for python3 installed, but I cannot get the VS terminal to access them to install modules and run my program.

I am using the command palette to select the interpreter and it says "current: /path/to/python3".

That is all good, but when I go to terminal to update my packages for I get this error that to me indicates that terminal is trying to install the package in the default python 2.7 environment. How do I access my python3 environments from this terminal? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: one solution: if you have the `python` package installed, try `cmd + shift + p` and type/select `run selection/line in terminal`.  this will open a terminal window with the interpreter associated with that file.  The interpreter associated with that file can be seen in the status bar at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

The best way to avoid this kind of trouble for each project/development environment is virtual environments.
Recomended read: https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/
You can use PipEnv https://github.com/pypa/pipenv or virtual env https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: Agreed, I messed with pyenv for a few hours trying to make that work to no avail. I did however figure out how to solve the problem. You can open the terminal in the correct interpreter and use "python3 -m pip install numpy" and in works like a charm.

Comment: messing it up a few times will help you understand it better and then avoid future pain by not doing it before

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you select a globally-installed interpreter it doesn't change what `python` points at in the terminal. You still need to specify either the full path to the interpreter or at least the major.minor version, e.g. `python3.7` to get the interpreter you want.

Otherwise you can use the advice provided by @paltaa and create a virtual environment to work from to isolate your work and put it all directly under your control.

Answer (score -2):

I also find the same problem when I was working on python 3. I Deleted the directory in which python 2.7 was installed. System automatically refer to Python 3 after that.

Comment: Do not do this. The system will fail